# Android Webview asset loading from root URL

Tags: android, html, webview

I using a webview to load my site from the assets folder with the help of WebViewAssetLoader.

The site is loaded like this:
webView.loadUrl("https://appassets.androidplatform.net/assets/index.html");

My problem is that because my webpage is not handling relative URLs, it is try to load some assets from the root folder. For example:
https://appassets.androidplatform.net/js/util.js

It's obviously not working because the correct path is assets/js/util.js. Can I somehow modify the webview implementation to load everything from the root URL?

Answer (score 0):

I made an interceptor for it:

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    WebResourceResponse intercepted = assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(request.getUrl());
    String url = request.getUrl().toString();

    if (url.contains("androidplatform.net/") && !url.contains("/assets/")) {
        Uri myUri =
                Uri.parse(url.replace("androidplatform.net/", "androidplatform.net/assets/"));

        intercepted = assetLoader.shouldInterceptRequest(myUri);
    }

    return intercepted;
}
```