# is google play allow me to open localhost to get files?

Tags: android, webview, google-play, localhost

This is my webview game, I run a localhost in the game to the local files in assets.
it's all good but I want to know if I'm allowed to run Localhost or if it violates Google Play's publishing rules.

```
    imports...
    
    webview webView.loadUrl("http://localhost:8080/index.html");...
    some codes...
        private class LocalWebServer extends NanoHTTPD {

            public LocalWebServer() {
                super(8080);
            }

            @Override
            public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
                String uri = session.getUri();
                String mimeType = null;
                String fileName = uri.substring(1); // Remove the leading '/'
                if (fileName.endsWith(".html")) {
                    mimeType = "text/html";
                } else if (fileName.endsWith(".css")) {
                    mimeType = "text/css";
                } else if (fileName.endsWith(".js")) {
                    mimeType = "application/javascript";
                } else if (fileName.endsWith(".json")) {
                    mimeType = "application/json";
                } else if (fileName.endsWith(".png")) {
                    mimeType = "image/png";
                } else if (fileName.endsWith(".mp3")) {
                    mimeType = "audio/mpeg";
                } else if (fileName.endsWith(".m4a")) {
                    mimeType = "audio/mp4";
                }

                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(fileName);
                    if (mimeType != null) {
                        return newChunkedResponse(Response.Status.OK, mimeType, inputStream);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND, "text/plain", "File not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are in a web view you don't need localhost (and allow clear text traffic). You can simply load resources directly using app code instead of running a web server: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76819823